# Bash store pid of command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem. I am trying to monitor a Java program. To do that I have a start/stop Bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
 case $1 in
    start)
       echo $$ > /var/script/myprogram/test.pid;
       (cd /var/script/myprogram/test; mvn exec:java)
       ;;
     stop) 
       kill $(cat test.pid);
       rm test.pid
       ;;
     *) 
       echo "usage: test {start|stop}" ;;
 esac
 exit 0
```

The problem is that the pid that I write in `test.pid` is not the pid number of the Java program, but the pid of the current Bash script. Is there a way to get the pid file of the started Java program and write that pid number to test.pid?

Comment: The better option might be to switch to `pkill -f '^mvn exec:java'` altogether.

Comment: (a) Ideally, use a `systemd` [user unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User) instead of a Bash script. That gives you, “for free”, the PID management as well as logging and status monitoring. (b) Less ideally, run it in the background and then wait for it. Synopsis: `mvn exec:java & pid="$!" ; echo "$pid" > test.pid ; wait -n "$pid"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons not to do what you are doing, but...a simple solution is to simply exec the java process so that the  two pids are the same:

```
start)
   echo $$ > /var/script/myprogram/test.pid;
   cd /var/script/myprogram/test
   exec mvn exec:java
   ;;
```

`exec` will cause the current process to replace itself with the `mvn` process, so `$$` is the correct pid.  Also, this cleans up the process table, since the startup script no longer exists as the parent of the `mvn`.

Note that this is atypical behavior for a startup script, since it will not exit until the `mvn` process exits, but since this is what your original script is doing, it seems...still bizarre.

Comment: Is it better to create a service for the java program?